# how to close swing JFrame inseparate listerner class (not inner class and ananumous inner class). setVisible(false) not accessble in another class

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

i wrote code as designing part in one class by extending `JFrame` class, and action listeners for buttons in another class(not inner class) and finally for main method i taken separate class. here in listener class i am closing present window and opening new window. i am able open new window. but i cant close existing window. please help me.(i am not able to access `setVisible()` method)
listener class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     //new window opens   
    EmbeddedBrowser eb = new EmbeddedBrowser();
    eb.setVisible(true);    //how to close previous window
}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more code. We don't have any idea of what the source of this event is, and how you created and added the listener. Provide an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

To close the previous window you must pass a reference to the JFrame in some way. Another method would be to get the JButton from the ActionEvent and climb up the parents (using JComponent#getParent) to find the JFrame (but I think of this as dirty workaround).

So you may use this listener class:

```
public class MyListener extends ActionListener {

    private JFrame frameToClose;

    public MyListener(JFrame frameToClose) {
        this.frameToClose = frameToClose;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //new window opens   
        EmbeddedBrowser eb= new EmbeddedBrowser();
        eb.setVisible(true);
        frameToClose.setVisible(false);
    }
```

}

Note that this matches what the compiler generates when using an inner / anonymous class.
If you do not need the frameToClose anymore you may call JFrame#disposed instead of setVisble(false).